# Task.Run occasionally fails silently when launched from MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asynchronous, fire-and-forget

I am attempting to generate PDF copies of specific forms within my MVC application. As this is time consuming, and the client does not need to wait for this generation to happen, I'm trying to trigger this as a series of Fire and Forget Tasks.

One hang-up of note is that I need to have the HttpContext established, or some underlying pieces of the code that I can't alter won't work. I believe I have dealt with this problem, but I wanted to call it out in case it matters.

Here is the function I am calling...

```
    private void AsyncPDFFormGeneration(string htmlOutput, string serverRelativePath, string serverURL, string signature, ScannedDocument document, HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current = httpContext;
            using (StreamWriter stw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(serverRelativePath), false, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
            {
                stw.Write(htmlOutput);
            }

            Doc ABCDoc = new Doc();
            ABCDoc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;
            int DocID = 0;
            DocID = ABCDoc.AddImageUrl(serverURL + serverRelativePath + "?dumb=" + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Second + DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            while (true)
            {
                ABCDoc.FrameRect();
                if (!ABCDoc.Chainable(DocID))
                    break;
                ABCDoc.TextStyle.LeftMargin = 100;
                ABCDoc.Page = ABCDoc.AddPage();
                DocID = ABCDoc.AddImageToChain(DocID);
            }//End while (true...

            for (int i = 1; i <= ABCDoc.PageCount; i++)
            {
                ABCDoc.PageNumber = i;
                ABCDoc.Flatten();
            }

            ScannedDocuments.AddScannedDocument(document, ABCDoc.GetData());

            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(serverRelativePath));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Exception is logged to the database, and if that fails, to the Event Log
        }
    }
```

Within, I am writing the String output of the HTML contents of the MVC Form in question to an html file, handing the path to that file to the PDF writer, generating the PDF, and then deleting the html file.

I'm calling it inside of a Controller POST method, like so:

```
Task.Run(() => AsyncPDFFormGeneration(htmlOutput, serverRelativePath,
    serverURL, signature, document, HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context));
```

This command is called as part of a foreach loop that constructs the forms, loads them into string format, and then passes them into a task. I've also tried this with

```
Task.Factory.StartNew
```

just in case something weird was going on with Task.Run, but that didn't produce a different result.

The problem I am having is that not all of the Tasks execute every time. If I run in Visual Studio and step my way through debugging, it works properly every time. However, when attempting to generate 11 forms sequentially, sometimes it generates all of them, sometimes it generated 3 or 4, sometimes it generates all but 1.

I have error logging set up to be as extensive as possible, but no exceptions are being thrown that I can find, and no generated html files are left lying around in my file structure on account of a thread aborted part-way.

There seems to be a slight correlation between how quickly the page comes back from the post, and how many of the forms are generated. A longer load time generally correlates to more of the forms being generated...but I was under the impression that shouldn't matter. I'm spinning these off to separate threads with their own copy of the HttpContext to take with them and carry around. Once launched, I did not think that the original thread should impact them.

Any ideas on why I'm only getting 3 successful Tasks on some attempts, all 11 on another attempt, and no exceptions?

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html You are currently doing the "ThreadPool" approach.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That seems related to the Application recycling. My problem is happening every single time I submit the page that generates these forms, generating a random number of those forms. Does the ThreadPool approach have the same problem with an individual Request Handler Thread shutting down after it responds to a request from a client?

Comment: Your threads are being suspended, as it's default behaviour for ASP.NET thread pool. Use stable service to queue some work, do not do that direcly in ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

```
Task.Run(() => AsyncPDFFormGeneration(htmlOutput, serverRelativePath,
serverURL, signature, document, HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context));
```

You have a subtle race condition on this line. The problem is with the `HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context` property. It will be evaluated when the task starts. If it happens before the end of the request, this is fine. But if for some reason the task takes a bit of time to start, then the request will complete first, and the `HttpContext` will be null. Therefore, you will have a null-reference exception, giving you the impression that the task didn't start (when, in fact, it did but crashed immediately outside of your try/catch).

To avoid that, just store the context in a local variable, and use it for `Task.Run`:

```
var context = HttpContext; // Or HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context, but I don't really see the point
Task.Run(() => AsyncPDFFormGeneration(htmlOutput, serverRelativePath, serverURL, signature, document, context));
```

That said, I don't know what API you are using that requres `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` to be set, but it seems a very bad choice for a fire-and-forget task. Even if you locally save the HttpContext, it'll still have been cleaned up, so I'm not sure it'll behave as expected.

Also, as was mentioned in the comments, launching fire-and-forget tasks on ASP.NET is dangerous. You should use [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](http://HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem) instead.

Comment: Why is this not marked as an answer? This is perfect! It helped me a tonne!

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3, etc)` as your application may be closing before all tasks have completed.

Comment: Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of using Fire and Forget tasks? I do not want to wait for the tasks to finish before I return a view to the user. I want the user to be able to move on to other things, while the PDFs continue to be generated in the background.

Comment: @guildsbounty You can't do fire and forget like that. Use traditional distributed processing techniques (message queues) or something like Hangfire.